# Doctrine relationship with non-entity model

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm trying to create an application where I have two related models: "User" and "Debtor".

User is a doctrine entity that is persisted in my database.
Debtor is a model that is stored on an external system and accessed through an API. I have already created a repository for accessing Debtors with find(), findAll() and findByUserId().

If "Debtor" was a Doctrine Entity, i would have a @OneToMany relationship on the User model in order to access debtors. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @OneToMany
     */
    private $debtors;

    public function getDebtors() {
        return $this->debtors;
    }

    public function setDebtors($debtors) {
        $this->debtors = $debtors;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

One solution would be to call DebtorRepository::findByUserId($this->id) in the getDebtors() method, but I don't think that is the right way to go.

I also thought about have a @PostLoad method that loads the users debtors into the $debtors property.

I'm not much for having that much logic inside my models, but i don't know what other choices I have?
Furthermore, I also need to be able to access various other models through the Debtor model and so i have the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

If resource for your API, I think you should have service which will take care of loading that (as probably you need to check for errors/authentication/...). So I would load it on demand from service.

But if you really want to have it accessible in the entity, then you can use [Entity Listener](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#entity-listeners), hook to the postLoad method and inject it there. In this case your entity will still stay thin, because this heavy logic will be in external service.